# How to prevent myself from updating my svn working copy

Tags: svn

Assume I have a working copy of a project versioned with svn. For a particular reason I want to keep a particular revision x of that project as my working copy. But sometimes I'm clumsy and I accidentally do an svn update to the latest revision y>x. Is there an easy way, to prevent svn updates on a working copy, like disabling the update command or something? Thanks.

Comment: On which platform are you developing on? (Unix/Windows)

Comment: With tortoise SVN on windows, you can remove the option from the right click context menu. (It's too easy to accidentally hit that update button when you meant to commit, there should be a are you sure dialog...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you checkout with 'svn export' rather than 'svn checkout' you'll get a copy without all the .svn info. That will stop you doing svn update since it's not a working copy at all.

It will also stop you doing "svn anything" on that tree (at least not without some gymnastics to make it a valid svn checkout)

Is that any good?

Comment: why would you want to do this when you have a proper mechanism? there's no difference between this and suggesting the OP to unplug the network cable

Answer (score 5):

You could make a [branch](http://research.mosuma.com/faq/howto/svn_branch_merge). More info on branching and merging can be find [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html#svn-ch-4-sect-1).

With a branch you can work all you want and doing `svn-up` will do anything since no one should be commiting to yout branch. Then, after all the work is done you just `merge` your work with the `trunk`

This should be best over exporting all the code from version control, since well, you just lose version control..

Comment: I just discovered, that I don't actually need version control. So exporting is the right choice for me. But in general, I agree with you on the branching solution.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the .svn directory in the directory that you do not want to update.  Rename the entries file to entrieszzz.  You won't be able to update or commit anything until you rename it back to entries.

Comment: Thanks. This also seems like a good way, because, if later I decide I want to do an update, I could re-rename the svn stuff to their original names.